# Heat preserving performance of container relative to content

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, everyday-life, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

This question has been addressed in the case of a thermos bottle:
[Performance of a thermos bottle relative to contents](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69235/performance-of-a-thermos-bottle-relative-to-contents)

I am asking the question again without the hypothesis that it is a
thermos bottle.

Given a container with a warm liquid inside ("warm" meaning warmer
than the medium surrounding the container), will it cool faster, slower
or equally, when it is half-full than when it is full.

To simplify the analysis, it is assumed that the opening and cap of
the container have the same properties with respect to heat as the
rest of the container, so that they may be ignored in the analysis.

Comment: @Dilaton Actually, I did not mean this at all as an everyday-life
question. I meant it as an "abstract" physical problem.  My reason for
the question was that I was not quite happy about the way the thermos case was
understood, and I am trying to push the problem further. Hence, I would
really like to know why the question was downvoted, not because I
resent the downvote, but because the reason may include some of the
information I am looking for. A simple downvote is hardly
constructive or informative. (I am not assuming you, @ Dilaton, downvoted)

Comment: Faster. $dT/dt=kT$. $k$ is decreases when the fullness increases because the vvolume is proportional to $r^3$ but, whereas, the surface area is proportional to $r^2$.

Comment: @babou: My answer to the previous question applies to all bottles, thermos or otherwise. Can you update your question to indicate what aspects of the problem is puzzling you.

Comment: Hi babou, I agree with what John Rennie said, maybe you could clarify a bit what phyics concepts you are thinking about in the context of this problem and take the tag away in this case. The downvote is not mine ;-).

Comment: @JohnRennie Your answer in the thermos case - if I understand
correctly - assumes fast heat propagation in the container (as
compared to loss through the sides). This is a very fair assumption in
the case of the thermos bottle (I am also trying to understand why
some types of answers are preferred to other types.) But I intentionally
placed my question in a different context, not making assumptions
about heat transfer speeds among other things.

Comment: @dimension10 I am aware of the issue of surface to volume ratio. That
is why babies or small dogs should not be left in a car in the sun or
in the cold (it applies to both heat and water loss). But can you
apply it as simply as that ?  To answer dilaton's remark, what I am
really interested in is the different ways people will reason about
the situation and the assumptions they make. I was motivated when I
realized I was making assumptions too. But this interest does not preclude that the question is answerable and that the answer has interest on its own.

Comment: Hi @Dilaton  ... did I answer fairly your question? I am fascinated that no one will try to answer (I do not mean that for you). Maybe you can tell me why, as you know this site much better than I do.

Comment: @dimension10 I wrote an answer to my question, which explains why the surface to
volume ratio can have a (mildly) paradoxical effect. What mattered to
me was no so much the result as the way people see the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started asking myself this question because I was somehow
unsatisfied with the answers to the previous question "[Performance of a
thermos bottle relative to contents](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69235/performance-of-a-thermos-bottle-relative-to-contents)"
concerning a very specific kind of container. There were assumptions
made in the answers. Even though these assumptions were fair, given
that a thermos bottle is a rather precise and well known object, the
reasonning in the answers did not make them explicit.  I tried to avoid
it, by reasonning explicitly about the cork of the bottle, but I still
used properties of the bottle shape without saying so explicitly (I
became aware of it later).  And even though my assumption was
close to the actual facts, a thermos bottle is not a cylinder. The
bottom is often somewhat spherical, which could have called for an
extra line of justifications (how high should the bottle be compared
to the radius of the bottom half sphere, unless the top is also
considered a half-sphere ?).

Sometimes, we also make (explicit or implicit) assumptions that are
not needed.

The other thing that bothered me is that people will often vote for
simple answers they understand quickly (not necessarily the best answer or even
a correct one). At least that is the feeling I get. If warranted, this would
justify making lots of unstated assumptions when answering. Not to
mention the fact that fast answers get a better chance at upvotes,
when acceptable.

Then, considering the thermos question, I started wondering about what
could make our statements wrong, and what could be the assumptions
that are often made implicitly, just for that kind of problem (though I
actually made one or two explicit in stating this new problem). Here are
some such assumptions, probably an incomplete list (other ideas are welcome):

- role of the cork: can it be ignored as not significant ?
- homogeneity of the bottle sides: is it the same kind of material all over ?
- shape of the container: is it just a bottle, which we tend to assume ?
- heat conductivity of the bottle side: is it isotropic ?
- uniformity of liquid cooling: well, that is always wrong, but liquid conductivity is so efficient that it seems a good approximation. Is it?

Then I wondered whether falsifying these assumptions could also
falsify the conclusion.

Once I had satisfied myself that it was the case, I asked the
question, carefully stated so as not to induce any assumption (for
example by always using the word "container" instead of "bottle"). I
was not trying to trap anyone, only experimenting. I unfortunately got
few reactions (thank you to those who did react).  I should have started
that more anonymously as some users clearly wondered what I was after
(comments welcome).

**So here is my answer.**

The picture is a cross-section image of a container that will cool faster
when it is full than when it is half-full. It consists of a large disk on
top of a sphere, with the same volume so that only the sphere contains
liquid when it is half-full. The opening between them is large so that
heat can flow easily between the two parts when it is full.

[image: weird container composed of a flat hollow disk atop a sphere with equal content]

Clearly, the disk has a very large surface to volume ratio and will
act effectively as a radiator to cool the liquid it contains, while
the shere has the smallest possible ratio and will not cool fast.
However, when the container is full, heat will flow through the liquid
from the sphere to the disk so that all the liquid content will cool
rather fast, though the disk will get cooler faster than the sphere.

If the container is only half-full, only the sphere contains warm
liquid, with a small surface/volume ratio. Hence it will cool more
slowly.

If the container is large enough, this should be sufficient.

It can be improved by remarking that a horizontal disk shape is not
very good for convection heat transfer. Replacing the hollow disk with
an inverted bell shape would work better.

You can even reinforce further the effect by using for the side of the
container a material that is more heat conductive transversally than
laterally, so that heat goes out quickly but is not conducted
efficiently from one part of the container side to another.  That
avoids heat being transferred to the disk when the container is half
full, and still permits the disk to cool efficiently the liquid it
contains when full. It can be easily produced by using a heat insulating
material with copper nails piercing it at close regular intervals.

The same effect could be achieved with a bottle having a standard
shape, but with isolation only in the bottom part.  This is somewhat
close to what I said about the effect of a conductive cork in the
thermos case.

Of course, this is no major discovery in elementary physics. At best a
moderately easy puzzle game. But it may be telling about our
reasonning process.

Coming back to the remark about votes. I am wondering whether the initial
downvote for that question (without an explicitly related explanatory
comment) was motivated by such an unstated assumption. Was it really
justified?

Now, it is possible that people who are very proficient in a field
will vote more accurately. It is probably more the case, but I think not always (I do have one example
in mind, not from physics).  Proficiency is an ill-defined concept,
and schools of thought are often biased, even in hard sciences.